# РодИлся или родилсЯ?

Tags: фонетика

Она - родилАсь, а вот он? По логике - родилсЯ, но как-то не звучит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое наблюдение:родиться - появиться на свет - сов.вид.(что сделал?)  родИлся в деревне( и разговорно-бытовой вар. родилсЯ в той стороне,она  родилАсь(разг. родИлась), родилОсь, родилИсь ; дети родилИсь в один день , но: дети родИлись каждый год (несов.в.)

Родиться -появляться, возникать- несов.вид:(что делает?)родИтся;(что делал?) постоянно родИлся какой-то новый замысел, родИлась(рожь), родИлось(много чего-то), родИлись, ; каждый день у него родИлись новые замыслы 
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%F0%EE%E4%E8%F2%FC%F1%FF

Answer (score 1):

Верны обе формы: родИлся, родИлась и родилсЯ, родилАсь.

Онегин, добрый мой приятель, родИлся на брегах Невы. Где родИлся, там и пригодился. И красный ландыш родилсЯ...Чтоб узнать, где родИлась река...Память возвращается, как птица, в то гнездо, в котором родилАсь.

Практически чаще встречаются формы родИлся и родилАсь, а варианты применяются в поэзии - для рифмы, наверное.

Comment: Серьезно? А когда я работала на телевидении и сказала в передаче "родИлась", меня поправили и пришлось переснимать эпизод!

Answer (score 0):

родилсЯ и родИлся. Проверила по Орфоэпическому словарю.